# TensorFlow: Binary classification accuracy

Tags: neural-network, confusion-matrix

In the context of a binary classification, I use a neural network with 1 hidden layer using a tanh activation function. The input is coming from a word2vect model and is normalized.

The classifier accuracy is between 49%-54%.

I used a confusion matrix to have a better understanding on what’s going on. I study the impact of feature number in input layer and the number of neurons in the hidden layer on the accuracy.

What I can observe from the confusion matrix is the fact that the model predict based on the parameters sometimes most of the lines as positives and sometimes most of the times as negatives.

Any suggestion why this issue happens? And which other points (other than input size and hidden layer size) might impact the accuracy of the classification?

Thanks

Comment: That's no better than a coin flip.  You should put the neural network aside and understand your data better before you do anything else.  I'd also recommend trying a logistic regression.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to guess given the information you provide.
Are the labels balanced (50% positives, 50% negatives)? So this would mean your network is not training at all as your performance corresponds to the random performance, roughly. Is there maybe a bug in the preprocessing? Or is the task too difficult? What is the training set size?

I don't believe that the number of neurons is the issue, as long as it's reasonable, i.e. hundreds or a few thousand.

Alternatively, you can try another loss function, namely cross entropy, which is standard for multi-class classification and can also be used for binary classification:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn/classification#softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

Hope this helps.

Comment: The data set is well balanced, 50% positive and negative.

The training set shape is (411426,X)

The training set shape is (68572,X)

X is the number of the feature coming from word2vec and I try with the values between [100,300]

I have 1 hidden layer, and the number of neurons that I test varied between [100,300]

I also test with mush smaller features/neurons size: 2-20 features and 10 neurons on the hidden layer.
I use also the cross entropy as cost fonction.

Comment: I strongly believe there is some error in the labels or somewhere else.
Given that you use word2vec as input, you already have a good representation. Thus, I suggest trying a linear model (SVM), which should certainly give a better than random performance, if the task is feasible. For this it would help to know what the task is? Is it realistic to hope a deep net can solve it?

Comment: To see if the problem is coming from my neural network implementation or input data, I used the tf-idf representation with to_dense() function.
The result with TF-IDF and a little change to parameters is 78% accuracy.

Comment: So the problem is coming from the fact that I’m using the word2vec as data input. The model generated with word2vec seems working fine:
model_train.most_similar(positive='tv'):
[('movies', 0.8289981484413147),
 ('hills', 0.7655214071273804),
 ('football', 0.7631117105484009),
 ('mtv', 0.7516076564788818),
 ('episodes', 0.7510683536529541),
 ('twilight', 0.7488611340522766),
 ('movie', 0.7444069981575012),
 ('quotthe', 0.7419215440750122),
 ('dvd', 0.7418527603149414),
...]
So might the problem coming from the variance of data? How can I check this point?

Answer (score -2):

The data set is well balanced, 50% positive and negative.

The training set shape is (411426,X)

The training set shape is (68572,X)

X is the number of the feature coming from word2vec and I try with the values between [100,300]

I have 1 hidden layer, and the number of neurons that I test varied between [100,300]

I also test with mush smaller features/neurons size: 2-20 features and 10 neurons on the hidden layer.
I use also the cross entropy as cost fonction.

Comment: Don't add answers; this isn't supposed to be a dialog.  Edit your original question.